# Karma Validation and CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application that loads and works properly but when I run Karma for the unit tests, I get this error:

**ERROR:**

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-appheader' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-appheader' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-appheader' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-appheader></app-appheader>
<app-appmenu></app-appmenu>
```

**app.component.html**

The content is very simple:

```
<html>
<app-appheader></app-appheader>
<app-appmenu></app-appmenu>
<app-appsettings></app-appsettings>
<app-appfooter></app-appfooter>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppheaderComponent } from './components/appheader/appheader.component';
import { AppfooterComponent } from './components/appfooter/appfooter.component';
import { AppmenuComponent } from './components/appmenu/appmenu.component';
import { AppsettingsComponent } from './components/appsettings/appsettings.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppheaderComponent,
    AppfooterComponent,
    AppmenuComponent,
    AppsettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**appheader.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appheader',
  templateUrl: './appheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appheader.component.css']
})
export class AppheaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

That is the code I'm running that works properly but that doesn't pass the unit test...

In this moment I have solved the problem by using a workaround by implementing [`NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`](https://angular.io/api/core/NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA) in the `spec.ts` file but I'm sure that is not the right way to move.

Comment: Have you tried to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA` in spec.ts?

Comment: How can I add it ?
" import { CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';  " is not compiling...

Comment: That solved my problem ! thanks !

Comment: This is a very pointless test. The component doesn't do anything. All it does is host some other components, and you're completely  overriding the fact they are not included by using CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA. If all the component does is host other components (with no behavior of it's own), I would just not test it. It's a waste of time. What are you actually going to test? That the component actually includes the components it's supposed to? If you are going to do that, then don't use CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA/NO_ERPOR_SCHEMA. Personally, I would not even test this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing this line:

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

and restarting the application with **ng serve**.

Ciao